# Assert without the traceback in Python

Tags: python, logic, assert

I'm trying to simplify the following:

```
if x < 0:
  print('we don't do negative numbers')
else: 
  NORMAL CODE HERE
```

I recently learned of the `assert` command, and admire its ability to simplify my previous lines into:

```
assert x > 0, 'errorText'
NORMAL CODE HERE
```

I don't want errors to give a traceback, though. I only want that single line like the if/else gives.

Is there a way to get an assertionError to return single line like exceptions do, or do I really need to keep running if/else's everywhere?

Comment: If you don't want a traceback, you're probably abusing `assert`. Check the manual for its real usage.

Comment: If x is runtime-variant don't `assert` but `raise` a **domain-specific** exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `assert` statement in Python is intended for debugging or for testing. It serves the purpose of halting execution of the program when the condition is not `True`. When debugging you can include these statements in your code to help track down errors. Then remove them once the bug is fixed. Using `assert` in production code is a bad idea.

As you have it written using `assert`, your program will terminate if x is less than zero and the code that follows will not run.

You should continue to use if/else method to provide the two desired code paths. One path to log that x is less than zero, the other path to execute the code in the block NORMAL CODE HERE.

If x should never be less than 0 at this point, and the remaining code must not be executed then you should raise an Exception that can be caught in the calling code.

```
def method_using_positive_numbers(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError("we don't do negative numbers")
    NORMAL CODE HERE
```

Another option is to return from the method if the condition is not true.

```
def method_using_positive_numbers(x):
    if x < 0:
        print("we don't do negative numbers")
        return
    NORMAL CODE HERE
```

Comment: This gives me exactly what I needed. An "if condition: return" basically does what I was hoping to do with the assert. Thank you for enlightening me on what assert is actually intended for.